# How do I restore the password from another installation?

Tags: password

I have Arch installed along with Ubuntu. I forgot the password for Arch. Luckily, I can read its `/etc/passwd` file. But I can't understand what the password really is and if it is there anyway or not. How or where do I find it?

P.S. I am aware about being able to boot through Live CD, but that's the harder path and there is no need in it since I am able to see the Arch's /etc/passwd file.

Answer (score 0):

There is this link for instructions on how to recover a password in linux  http://www.debuntu.org/how-to-recover-root-password-under-linux-with-single-user-mode/